# How to set value in hundreds?

Tags: javascript, rounding

Is there a way to set the value of a field in hundreds?

For example, if value is less than or equal to 100 value is changed to 100 or if value is less than equal to 200 value is 200 and so on.

Comment: `value = ((value / 100) | 0) * 100;` We divide it by 100, only look at its integer part, then multiply that by 100.

Comment: Ah right, I misread. If you need to round up Guffa's solution is good (if you want to stay fancy you can add 1 after dividing)

Comment: I don't think we are in the same question.. no rounding numbers is given..

Comment: I think I just got what you wanted to accomplish, see if my answer suits your needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Divide by 100, use `Math.ceil` to round up, and multiply by 100:

```
x = Math.ceil(x / 100) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
function inHundreds(x) {
    return Math.ceil(x/100)*100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with jQuery:

```
var value = $('#field').val();  // checked what value you got by field id
value = Math.round(value/100); // divide, to know how many hundreds it have
if(value > 0)
{
   $('#field').val(value*100); // set value to field
} else {
$('#field').val('100');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about JavaScript Math.ceil() function? It rounds up any value you provide. Use base = 100 to round it to hundreds.

```
var base = 100;
var x = 98;
x = base * (Math.ceil(x / base));
alert(x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Anx7/